# image caption generator jscript

Tags: generator, jscript

I am using ght ebelow script to get the image name in title and alt attribute.

```
var $img = $(this);
var filename = $img.attr('src')
$img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

my question is there ant posibility of generating the caption using image title.

Comment: "is there ant posibility of generating the caption using image title." can you explain it little more?

Comment: Yesterday I also tried for the same But i got nothing in the google and outside it. If u found a sample also tel me i will make it possible.

Comment: hey i asked you to explain your question little more. So, i can help! i can make anything for you bro :D

Comment: Can we auto insert images in blogger after uploading completes. This is my new question. Can you do this using jscript of html.

Comment: for this question, I have answered. Can You please explain your new question more? everything is possible :D

Comment: While uploading images in to my post i want to auto insert the images into post after uploading. If you have a google account. Go to Blogger and create a blog and upload an image then you have to press insert selected Button to insert images in to post. I want to Auto insert images in to post after uploading is complete. I really need your help.

Comment: oh you wanna preview that uploaded images when they have completed uploading?

Comment: nearly Dude You tell me the way to do that 1st if i got it i will comform you.

Comment: hahahahh :P see this : http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html there is demo also!

Comment: No No they are not working. My question is How to Auto Insert images after uploading is complete in a Blog(Blogger) Not wordpress..?

Comment: well, you have asked a difficult question. Post it as a question on stackoverflow.com and i figure it out :D if i can't maybe others can help you!

Comment: i have already asked this question on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function () {
  var $img = $(this);
  var filename = $img.attr('src')
  $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
  $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
});
```